# SwiftUI/ Combine Listen to multiple publishers inside an ObservableObject

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, combine

I have an `ObservableObject` which inside has two more `ObservableObjects`. Each of these two `ObservableObject` has one or more `@Published` properties inside. My solution works but I'm 100% sure there must be another way. I have to copy/ paste everything in order to make it work. I tried two put those two publishers in the View but then I need to pass a lot of params to the child view. Any ideas how to simplify this?

```
class PackageService: ObservableObject {
    @Published var package: Package
    @Published var error: Error?
    
    @Published var distance: Double?
    @Published var expectedTravelTime: String?
    
    @Published var amount: Int = 0
    @Published var cost: Double = 0
    
    @Published var annotations = [MKPointAnnotation]()

    @Published var isCalculating = true
    @Published var route: MKRoute?
    
    var amountService = AmountService()
    var routeService = RouteService()
    
    private var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()
    
    init(package: Package) {
        self.package = package
        routeService.calcDirections(source: package.source.toCLLocationCoordinate2D, destination: package.destination.toCLLocationCoordinate2D)
        
        routeService.$route.sink { [self] route in
            self.route = route
            
            amountService.calc(distance: route?.distance)
            calc(route: route)
        }
        .store(in: &cancellables)
        
        routeService.$isCalculating.sink { [self] isCalculating in
            self.isCalculating = isCalculating
        }
        .store(in: &cancellables)
        
        
        routeService.$error.sink { [self] error in
            self.error = error
        }
        .store(in: &cancellables)
        
        amountService.$amount.sink { [self] amount in
            self.amount = amount
        }
        .store(in: &cancellables)
        
        amountService.$cost.sink { [self] cost in
            self.cost = cost
        }
        .store(in: &cancellables)
        
        amountService.$error.sink { [self] error in
            self.error = error
        }
        .store(in: &cancellables)
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like the `PackageService` is just a thin wrapper around two other services.

It would make sense to use computed properties instead of subscribing and publishing a change for each property:

```
var isCalculating: Bool { routeService.isCalculating }

var amount: Int { amountService.amount }

// etc...
```

and to subscribe once in order to signal changes to the view:

```
routeService.objectWillChange
            .merge(with: amountService.objectWillChange)
            .sink(receiveValue: self.objectWillChange.send)
            .store(in: &cancellables)
```

---

Also, consider packaging the various properties in a single data model, e.g.:

```
struct AmountModel {
   var amount: Int
   var cost: Double
}
```

and have the `AmountService` have a single property. This could be a `Result<AmountModel, Error>` to capture either the data or the error, or, if you need, include the `Error` as a property.

Comment: Great answer, I knew it could be simplified.

Comment: but how do I react to changes inside `routeService` since when a property inside routeService is updated I need to trigger `amountService.calc(distance: route?.distance)`

Comment: @M1X, if you need to perform some action unrelated to SwiftUI, then yeah, you could observe with Combine, e.g. `route.$distance.sink`... but you asked about observing in SwiftUI. All SwiftUI needs (this also answers your second comment's question) is to know that something is changed (see `.sink(receiveValue: self.objectWillChange.send)` in my answer), and then it reloads the view. So, you could do `.onChange(packageSvc.distance) { packageSvc.recalcAmount() }`

Comment: Ok I think I got it `.sink(receiveValue: self.objectWillChange.send)` notifies the View.  `.onChange(packageSvc.distance) { packageSvc.recalcAmount() }` to catch the changes in the view. And if I want to perform some action I need to use `sink`.

Comment: Also strange but a computed property which returns a `@Published` will reflect the changes to the view even without .sink(receiveValue: self.objectWillChange.send)